# Iterating through layers in mxd and describing coordinate system

Tags: arcpy, coordinate-system

I have mxd's that have information loaded from many different locations (some FCs from FGDB, shps, FCs in EGDB) and I want to check the coordinate reference system quickly for them. I have attempted the code below but get a error on line 16 for unsupoported operand type for +: 'layer' and 'str'.

```
import arcpy

mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")  # Uses your currently open MXD
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, '')[0] # Chooses the first dataframe
layerlist = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers


for layer in layerlist(mxd, '', df): # Loop through layers
    sr = arcpy.Describe(layer).spatialReference
    if sr.name == "Unknown":
        print layer + " has an unknown spatial reference\n"

    # Otherwise, print out the feature class name and
    #   spatial reference
else:
    print layer + ": " + sr.name + "\n"
```

Comment: Should the else line have the same indentation as the if statement?

Comment: Use layer.name + sr.name

Comment: and use spatialReference.type (if sr.type == 'Unknown':)  instead of sr.name http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//018z0000000v000000 . If you create a spatial reference with parameters the name could be 'Unknown' but the spatial reference is *not* unknown, just custom. Spatial reference type property knows if the spatial reference is  Geographic, Projected or Unknown, even if it is custom. It's also a good idea to check if a layer is feature (isFeatureLayer) or raster and if it is indeed valid (isBroken == False).